# append filenames matching with sequential numbers

Tags: bash, rename, string-matching, sequential

I'm trying to add/modify filenames by adding sequential numbers to files that have matching filenames. I'm still learning but based on a number of posts from SO I've been able to get close. The problem is the code below add numbers sequentially to all files, not based on matching filenames.

```
e='t'
j=1
basename="$1"
newname="$2"
for f in "$basename"*.run?.t
do
    echo mv -- "$f" "$newname${f#$basename%.run*.t}.run$((j++)).$e"
done
```

Here's a simplified version of my files:

```
1234.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t
1234.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t
1234.Gorilla_sub3.run1.t
1234.Gorilla_sub1.run2.t
1234.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t

4578.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t
4578.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t
```

I want:

```
1234.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t
1234.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t
1234.Gorilla_sub3.run3.t
1234.Gorilla_sub1.run4.t
1234.Gorilla_sub2.run5.t

4578.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t
4578.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t
```

But my code above does this:

```
1234.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t.run1.t
1234.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t.run2.t
1234.Gorilla_sub3.run1.t.run3.t
1234.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t.run4.t
1234.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t.run5.t

4578.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t.run6.t
4578.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t.run7.t
```

How can I get it to restart the numbering based on the same filenames prefix (1234.Gorilla, 4578.Gorilla)? Also replace the run?.t rather than add it on? The part of the file reading sub? I'll actually remove later, if that makes a difference.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please indent your code and provide better input examples

Comment: You input samples are repeated files... And you want them to finish with ".t"? With ".1"? Or with whatever it was there in the first place? Your code above cannot give the output you say you are getting.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the example to better match my files.

Comment: Do you need to retain ordering?

Comment: No, I don't think if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @NKN If `1234.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t` must be `1234.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t` or it can be `1234.Gorilla_sub2.run3.t` for example and some other `1234` file can be `run2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then you should reset j after reaching 2.
Using your code:

```
e='t'
j=1
basename="$1"
newname="$2"
for f in "$basename"*.run?.t
do
    echo mv -- "$f" "$newname${f#$basename%.run*.t}.run$((j++)).$e"
    if (( j == 2 )); then 
        $(( j = 1 )); 
    fi;
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I actually will have up to hundreds of files per each unique basename.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order is important, take a look at this *lovely and highly readable* code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash   

declare -A a
shopt -s extglob nullglob

reg='_sub([0-9]+).run([0-9]+).t$'

for f in *_sub+([0-9]).run+([0-9]).t; do
    [[ $f =~ $reg ]] && printf '%d %d %s\0' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}" "$f"
done | sort -zn -k2,2 -k1,1 | cut -zd' ' -f3- |
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    echo mv -- "$f" "${f%.*.t}.run$((++a[${f%_*}])).t"
done
```

---

**Test run:**

```
mv -- 1234.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t 1234.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t
mv -- 4578.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t 4578.Gorilla_sub1.run1.t
mv -- 1234.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t 1234.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t
mv -- 4578.Gorilla_sub2.run1.t 4578.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t
mv -- 1234.Gorilla_sub3.run1.t 1234.Gorilla_sub3.run3.t
mv -- 1234.Gorilla_sub1.run2.t 1234.Gorilla_sub1.run4.t
mv -- 1234.Gorilla_sub2.run2.t 1234.Gorilla_sub2.run5.t
```

Remove `echo` if you are satisfied with the result.